# При считывании html в консоль , дата не отображается корректно (в отличии от других символов)

Tags: java

Подскажите как получить корректную дату в тексте при считывании html страницы.для считывания страницы использую такой код

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

            try
            {
                URL url = new 
URL("https://korrespondent.net/all/2018/june/1/");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(url.openConnection().getInputStream()));
                String s;
                while((s = br.readLine())!=null){
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
                br.close();
            }catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

  }
}
```

Comment: в консоли появляется примерно такой текст - ".....
                <div class="article__date">
                    <a href="https://korrespondent.net/ukraine/" class="article__rubric">Новости Украины</a> - 1&nbsp;июня 2018, 23:48
                </div>....." кирилица отображается корректно а вот дата нет..

Comment: все корректно считывает. &nbsp; - это неращрывный пробел. а что вы ожидали?

Comment: @Senior Pomidor то есть мне дату нужно читать "1&nbsp;июня 2018, " = " 1 июня 2018 " - ?...я пока что абсолютный чайник по этому и вопросы такие детские...

Comment: Тогда у меня еще вопрос как распознать дату в виде "1&nbsp;июня 2018 " стандартными инструментами Java

Comment: стандартными инструментами Java  метод format.parse(str) нормально распознает в формате "dd/MMMM/yyyy" или "dd.MMMM.yyyy" ("01/июня/2018" и "01.июня.2018"  соответственно а вот "1&nbsp;июня 2018 " не распознает...нужно писать какой то свой метод что бы приводить формат даты в тексте в нужный шаблон?

Comment: может быть лучше и проще сделать `result.replaseAll("&nbsp;", "");` ?

Comment: отлично, что то вроде этого и скал... @Senior Pomidor спасибо !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данные считываются корректно. `&nbsp;` - это [неразрывный пробел](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB).
Вам нужно просто заменить данный символ на пробел обычный.

```
s.replaseAll("&nbsp;", " ");
```

Comment: так и сделал, спасибо все работает....

Comment: когда ответ решает вашу проблему, вы можете нажать на галочку и принять ответ как верный.

Comment: спасибо буду знать